# Compare use of words in two strings in PHP

Tags: php

How do I compare the similarity of words in sentences, instead of the characters in a sentence.

I am aware of

```
similar_text($strA, $strB, $percentage);
```

to return the percentage of similarity between two strings, but how could I do this for words. So instead of looking at similarities between the characters in strings it would instead compare the content of different words.

The only way I could think of to achieve this is to assign each word (bit between the spaces) with a number and compare the numbers used, but this can't be the best method for solving this. It would be just plain overcomplicating, as far as I can see.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please mention some possible aproaches to solve the problem and what have you tried

Comment: explode the strings by words into arrays, array_intersect(), then see how many words are in common between the two.

Comment: @MarcB Ok great, that works but can I turn these numbers into percentages so I can find if these strings are more than n% similar? (Or something to the same effect

Comment: `count(common words) / count(total words in one array) * 100`. e.g. you have arrays with 20 and 30 words each, and your intersection produces 5. so 5/20 = 25% common with one array, and 5/30 = 16.7% common with the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count(common words) / count(total words in one array) * 100.
e.g. you have arrays with 20 and 30 words each, and your intersection produces 5. so 5/20 = 25% common with one array, and 5/30 = 16.7% common with the other.

Submitted by Marc B